# Nodemailer does not send mails after saving json file

Tags: json, node.js, nodemailer

I receive post requst and then process data sent with form. Everything works fine, until I add part with saving some data to json file.
My problem is inside callback of save() method on dataModel from mongoose.
Code looks like this:

```
dataModel.save((err, doc) => {
    if(err)
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    else {
        let time = Date.parse(doc.expirationDate);
        fs.readFile('./db.json', (err, data) => {
            if(err)
                console.log('Error: ', err);

            data = JSON.parse(data);
            data.timers.push({'id': doc._id, time: time});
            fs.writeFile('./db.json', JSON.stringify(data), err => {
                if(err)
                    console.log('Error: ', err);
            });
        });

        mailer.transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'Me <me@gmail.com>',
            to: `you@gmail.com`,
            subject: 'Subject',
            html: `<h1>Something</h1>`,
            text: `Something`
        }, (err, info) => {
            if(err)
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            else
                console.log('Mail has been sent. ', info.response);
        });
        mailer.transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'Me <me@gmail.com>',
            to: `someoneelse@gmail.com`,
            subject: 'Different subject',
            html: `Different message`,
            text: 'Different message'
        }, (err, info) => {
            if(err)
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            else
                console.log('Mail has been sent. ', info.response);
        });
    }
});
```

What is completely strange is that with this code, json file saves properly but mails are not sent, but if I comment part with saving db.json file, mails sends properly. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does your actual code attempt use the `data` variables that you read with `fs.readFile()` or the resulting file when sending the emails.  Because as you've written the code, the emails get sent BEFORE you finish reading or writing to your file so if they were waiting for something there, the code will not work.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, they are using fields from `doc` variable, which is send on `dataModel.save()` callback. I was even trying to put `mailer.transporter.sendMail()` inside `fs.writeFile()` callback or save `db.json` after sending mails but it doesn't matter - result is the same.

Comment: Well, there does not appear to be anything wrong with the code you show so there must be something else contributing to the problem in code you aren't showing us.